# Rails ActiveRecord where clause with .first vs .last in local vs production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, query-performance

I use Rails 5 and Postgres. I have a table name `buckets`, none of the columns are indexed. On my local machine I create 55,000 dummy record. I only need to get one record with has bucket_type is equal PR and issued_date is nil (there are 7 different bucket_type such as PR, CA, US, EU, VN, BU, and GY), so I try 2 different query one with `.first` and one with `.last` to see which one performs faster.

`Bucket.where({issued_date: nil, bucket_type: 'PR'}).first` and this query take about 1.5ms

`Bucket.where({issued_date: nil, bucket_type: 'PR'}).last` and this query take about 6.5ms

However when on production (Heroku), with 2.1 million record in buckets table, the result come out opposite:

`Bucket.where({issued_date: nil, bucket_type: 'PR'}).first` and this query take about 750ms

`Bucket.where({issued_date: nil, bucket_type: 'PR'}).last` and this query take about 150ms

I have 2 questions:

1. Why the performance of `.first` and `.last` after `where` clause is different on local vs on production?
2. Is there any better way than above query to get one record with has bucket_type is equal PR and issued_date is nil **without having to add any index** to either `bucket_type` or `issued_date`, or both columns?

Comment: You have a typo in your example, which may be part of the problem. You are missing a closing parenthesis before your `.first`/`.last` calls. Should look like this: `Bucket.where({issued_date: nil, bucket_type: 'PR'}).first`

Comment: @Andrew good catch it was just a typo when I typed in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really tell you then answer of the first question, but for the second,
well, you should use `limit`.

Lets have a look at the difference:

```
User.where(is_disabled: 0).first
# Oracle
SELECT * FROM ( 
  SELECT  "USERS".* FROM "USERS" WHERE "USERS"."IS_DISABLED" = :a1 
  ORDER BY "USERS"."ID" ASC 
) WHERE ROWNUM <= :a2
# MariaDB
SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`is_disabled` = 0 
ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

you see in oracle first all users are selected, and then the query is wrapped to only select the first. This is of course bad, MySQL/MariaDB doesn't do that. but sorts by the user_id (well rails does not MariaDB)

```
User.where(is_disabled: 0).limit(1)
# Oracle
SELECT  "USERS".* FROM "USERS" WHERE "USERS"."IS_DISABLED" = :a1 
AND ROWNUM <= :a2 
#MariaDB
SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`is_disabled` = 1 LIMIT 1
```

Here in Oracle only one user gets selected from the start, which is faster.
MariaDB does not sort the users which is also faster.

P.S. This can maybe change depending on the used Database, but `limit` is the way to go anyway. But your question 1 is not solvable as long as we don't know the used database. Furthermore, this should be splitted in two questions

Comment: Thanks for your response. `Bucket.where({issued_date: nil, bucket_type: 'PR'}.first` is equivalent to `SELECT  "buckets".* FROM "buckets" WHERE "buckets"."bucket_type" = $1 AND "buckets"."issued_date" IS NULL  ORDER BY "buckets"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["bucket_type", "PR"]]`  and same for `.last` the order will become `DESC`.

Comment: I know, have a look at the mariaDB part of the first code block of my answer. `limit` will remove the "useless" `ORDER BY`.

Comment: surprisingly when i remove ORDER BY the query time is longer :( as I did try `SELECT buckets.* FROM buckets WHERE issued_date IS NULL and bucket_type = 'PR' LIMIT 1`. This `SELECT buckets.* FROM buckets WHERE issued_date IS NULL and bucket_type = 'PR' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` is still the winner